# How to fix the space flex children takes in flex-direction colum?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use flex with direction column. If child has inner div which is larger than the container, it makes flex children to have uneven space. I can fix this problem using `min-width:0` if I am using `flex-direction:row` but I cant find any solution when we have columnar flex. I want flex items to take same amount of space no matter what their children's contents are.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:3px solid red;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin:3px;
}
.item2 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin:3px;
}
.inner{
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">
    item 2
    <div class="inner">
      ....inner
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is one case where Grid is much better: `.container {display: grid; grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;}`.

Comment: @ralph.m thanks a lot. This is great solution. Except on thing that my second div is optional, so in case it is not present i will have to see how to configure grid so that the first takes up the entire space. with `grid; grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;` first div is taking only 50% even if the second one is not present

Comment: Use `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` instead of `grid-template-rows`

Comment: Yes, Tim R is right: `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` is perfect for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This css code is make evenly spaces in row after fill items then auto start with new lines. its also responsive

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:evenly;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 
}

.item1 {
 
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin:3px;
}
.item2 {

  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin:3px;
}
.inner{
  
}
```

Comment: It appears that you attempted to address the space *between* the items with `justify-content: space-evenly`. However, that was not the question. This answer does not provide a solution for making the items equal in size.